# why is regex constructor not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was answering a question, and the following returns `false`

```
var regexp = new RegExp("([\w\.-]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
var result = regexp.test( $("#email").val() ); // returns false
```

While

```
var regexp = /([\w\.-]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})/;
var result = regexp.test( $("#email").val() ); // returns true
```

Why is that??

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape `\` when you use `RegExp` constructor function.

```
new RegExp("([\\w\\.-]+)@((?:[\\w]+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})");
```

Quoting from [MDN's `RegExp` constructor Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description),

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary. For example, the following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> var re = /\w+/;
> var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
> ```